# If border control refuses me entry at the airport, can I fly to any chosen country or only the country of origin?

Tags: air-travel, airports, airport-transfer, borders, denial-of-entry

The scenario:

1. a person is flying from country `A` to country `B`
2. upon landing, they are refused entry to the country `B` by the border control

question: instead of flying back to `A`, can they book the next flight to a country `C` and fly there?

EDIT: I was asked to make the scenario more specific, so:

Let's say a citizen of Hong Kong wants to go on a trip to Europe. They chose UK as the first country they will visit.

Hong Kong is a "Special Administrative Region", therefore they do not require a visa to enter the UK, yet border control decides to refuse entry (for whatever reason, but let's assume the traveler did nothing illegal).

The traveler doesn't want to waste his holidays and go back home disappointed. Can he now chose to take a flight to a different European country, such as Germany? (they don't need a visa there either thanks to a visa-waiver program)

Comment: That depends on how they do things in country B, which is different between different countries. The question is impossible to answer unless you specify what B is.

Comment: @Jezor Probably also depends on whether the individual has the right to enter country C

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I updated my question with a more detailed scenario (:

Comment: FWIW, I asked [a similar question, about the USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72136/what-is-the-practical-consequence-of-being-denied-entry-into-the-us-for-a-layove) a few years ago, but the answers I got were based more on speculation than on hard information.

Comment: There is no rule here, it is going to be decided in the circumstance. In many cases there will not be any direct flights between the two countries, or the person may not maintain a residence in the country of her citizenship. Many people refused entry will be surprised and confused about it, and not seek to interfere with the local authorities; others will have clear and precise goals.

Comment: @HenningMakholm what hard information do you want when there’s none?

Comment: @MusoniusRufus: I'm mentioning the earlier question as a way to suggest that there may not be any hard information to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhat similar question answered here [Removal at the expense of the Secretary of State?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100627/removal-at-the-expense-of-the-secretary-of-state)

> It is up to the airline that the passenger arrives on to decide
>   whether or not to allow him/her to travel to another country that will
>   accept him/her.

Typically the UK Immigration (and the airline) want to remove you expeditiously and to a **guaranteed** location. Any country except your home country is not guaranteed to accept you.

To answer your question more directly, the probability is slim however it is possible and I recollect having read somewhere someone received that exercise of discretion from UK Immigration/airline officials. It is not your right you can insist on. You have to be very persuasive and catch a streak of good luck.

Comment: so basically: put on a big smile and pray that it works out, gotcha